# Getting server side PHP script to run from android apk call

Tags: php, android

I've gotten HTTP POST to send strings to the server side PHP script. My log is showing the correct return values. The script runs fine manually from the browser and inserts a new db table row. But can't get the script to run by having the apk call it... though, again, it returns all script page content including strings.

How can I get the script to run?

Thanks
Allen

Comment: you should post relevant parts of your code. How do you call the script from your app?

Comment: HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       String url = MgActivity.SERVER_PREFERENCES_URL;
       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
       ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(USERID_KEY, user));
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PREF_PAINTING_KEY, prefPainting));
       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your dealing with a cahceing issue.  try adding a timestamp to the end of the url.

Comment: Here's the code...      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); String url = MgActivity.SERVER_PREFERENCES_URL; HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url); ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(USERID_KEY, user)); nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PREF_PAINTING_KEY, prefPainting)); httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);